# XML Transform FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, xml, libgdx, directory, filenotfoundexception

I'm creating a game using LibGDX and I want to create a XML file so I can save some configuration settings.

I want the file to be inside the assets folder, inside another directory (assets/xml/ajustes.xml)

If I execute the game as a Desktop Application it works OK, if the XML directory doesn't exist it is created and after that the XML file is created inside it. The problem comes when I execute the game in my Android device. I get an exception:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /xml/datos.xml (No such file or directory)
```

I cannot figure out where the problem is ...

This is what I wrote:

```
public static final String localizacionXML = "xml/datos.xml";

...

try {

        //THE xml DIRECTORY SHOULD BE CREATED HERE
        File dir = new File("xml");
        dir.mkdirs();

        File f = new File(localizacionXML);

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        //IF XML ALREADY EXISTS
        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            ...
        }else{
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = 
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

            ...

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = 
            TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new 
                File(localizacionXML).getAbsolutePath());

            //EXCEPTION HERE
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to files in the assets folder by using a relative path you had to use Gdx.files.internal(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ASSETS)

By using this method you get a FileHandle, which holds the file you want to use.

[Click here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) to visit the wiki page of file handling in libGDX.

Answer (score 0):

To save user data you might want to use Preferences instead.
You can save and load user preferences super easily

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

It will manage the XML file for you

That said, more generically speaking, to load a file you use Gdx.files.internal(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ASSETS)